# отсутствует api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll. что с этим делать?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

хотел запустить программу SoundBridge, но вылезла эта ошибка:
[image]
это есть та самая ошибка которая выскочила при открытии программы и что с этим делать?

Comment: Как советуют серьезные люди :) - (пере)установить Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_prog/api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0dll-is-missing/02b7b084-b6fd-44ea-bec7-f3297a11ec6c

Comment: пробовал,все равно ошибка лезет

Comment: @Harry, vcredist'ов хренова гора весрий. По 2 на каждую версию Visual Studio. Тут будет корректнее советовать поставить себе ВСЕ версии vcredist.